# Percent diff between first in sequence and each successive

Tags: r

I have sequences of data in a data frame at which I want perform a % change calculation on the first number in the sequence and each successive number, this is on matching +1 in response column. It would save the first number in data and loop through each number taking a percentage difference between first number and each successive number using data column. When response = 0, then the percent differences would cease.

```
    response    data    output
1    0          98.92     0
2    0          99.92     0
3    0          101.12    0
4    0          101.24    0
5    1          100.96    0
6    1          101.76    0.00792393
7    1          101.96    0.009904913
8    1          101.88    0.00911252
9    1          101.8     0.008320127
10    1         101.6     0.006339144
11    1         101.08    0.00118859
12    1         101.28    0.003169572
13    1         101.76    0.00792393
14    1         105.2     0.04199683
15    1         105.72    0.047147385
16    1         106.00    0.049920761
17    1         105.96    0.049524564
18    1         106.2     0.051901743
19    1         105.12    0.041204437
20    1         106.00    0.049920761
21    1         106.18    0.051703645
22    1         106.56    0.055467512
23    1         107.16    0.06141046
24    1         106.53    0.055170365
25    1         105.6     0.045958796
26    1         106.00    0.049920761
27    1         105.44    0.04437401
28    1         105.6     0.045958796
29    1         104.84    0.038431062
30    0         104.68    0
31    0         105.12    0
32    0         105.68    0
33    0         106.28    0
34    0         106.32    0
35    0         107.04    0
36    1         107.04    0
37    1         106.8     -0.002242152
38    1         107.04    0
39    1         107.2     0.001494768
40    1         109.16    0.01980568
41    1         109.24    0.020553064
42    1         109.28    0.020926756
43    1         110.28    0.030269058
44    1         110.56    0.032884903
45    1         109.68    0.024663677
46    1         108.48    0.013452915
47    1         107.24    0.00186846
48    1         107.88    0.007847534
49    1         107.84    0.007473842
50    1         107.48    0.004110613
51    0         108.16    0
52    0         108.36    0
53    0         103.28    0
54    0         104.84    0
```

on line 5 response is 1 however as its first in sequence no percent diff is calculated. Next on line 6 there is a +1 in response so that would take `percent diff between data col, line 5 and 6`. After this, we go to line 7, where it does a percent diff between `data col, line 7 and 5`. next percent diff between `data col, 8 and 5 etc...` until response is 0... it would do nothing until next sequence at line 36.

The above is example data with example percent diff in the output column.

EDIT:

I am trying to do this, create a function for taking percent diff... record first price on enter.long == 1, then do the percent diff against the first value..

```
# Calculate % diff
train.set$pct.diff <- function(x){
  d = diff(train.set$Close)
  print(d)
  for (j in 1:nrow(train.set)){
    if (train.set$enter.long[j] == 1)
    PCT[j]=d[j] / train.set$Close [j]
    print(PCT)
  }
  return(PCT)
}
```

need to turn off when meet a 0.. 
still working on it.

Comment: What have you tried that doesn't work for you?

Comment: `ave(df$data, df$response, FUN = function(x){(x - x[1]) / x[1]})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data

I made up 2 column `data.frame` with `response` and `data`

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(response=rep(c(0,1,0), each=10),
             data=runif(30)+100)
```

#### dplyr solution

Create `grp` when `response` changes value; make new column of values equal to first element of `data` in each group; calculate % difference if `response==1`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
         mutate(grp = cumsum(lag(response, default=head(response,1)) != response)) %>%     # make groups
         group_by(grp) %>%
         mutate(first = head(data,1)) %>%      # make new column with first element
         mutate(output = ifelse(response==1, (data-first)/first ,0)) %>%   # calculation
         ungroup() %>%
         select(-grp, -first)      # discard intermediate columns
```

#### Output

```
   response     data output
 1        0 100.2655      0
 2        0 100.3721      0
 3        0 100.5729      0
 4        0 100.9082      0
 5        0 100.2017      0
 # etc
```

Comment: Chi Pak - You are the man! Thank you very very much!!! Dplyr looks super powerful, do you know of any tutorials of the nature above?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html this shows this a little. So on every series of response ==1, we make that a group and we are setting lag to 1 to miss first instance, after on first response == 1, grab the data... next set mutate(first = head(data,1)) is the data,1 saying the 1 is a column OR is that a lag 1? this is part still knows its the group, so it always knows the start point first? so  set first = data... then over the group of response ==1's do the if response == 1, data (rolling) - first / first... next

Comment: the ungroup %>%... does this happen for every response ==1 series or group? or is that executed at the end of the whole series?? trying to understand this, I think its grouping every consecutive response ==1 series.. and doing the logic.. is this correct? what does != response) do? thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your first question...Regarding the second, it's important to clarify what `group` does. Each unique variable in `grp` will become a group. `ungroup` removes any grouping variable, which is only necessary to unselect the `grp` column. `!=` means `does not equal`

Comment: Ok makes sense, grab the response == 1, group them, then do the logic. I think it makes sense. Does it ungroup on each successive series of response ==1?

Comment: It'll `ungroup` all groups. In this particular case, `grp 1 = run-of-0`, `grp 2 = run-of-1`, `grp 3 = run-of-0`, etc.